# Where is a list of all of the operators in a where clause?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm asking about Query Operators like `=`, `<`, `>`, `like`, `and`, and `or`.

I'm using Mongoose version `4.0.2.`.

I found [a Mongoose link](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html), and [a Mongo link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/).

Neither answer my question.  For example, when I tried to use `.$eq()` it failed and I had to use `.equal()`.

Here is a code snippet:

```
// THIS DOES NOT WORK
var aQuery = MyMongooseModel.find({});
aQuery.where("firstName").$eq("Pat");
aQuery.exec(function(err, arMyMongooseModel){
    console.log("documents that have firstName='Pat'", arMyMongooseModel);
});
```

doesn't work, but if I change `.$eq` to `.equals` it does work.

```
// THIS DOES WORK
var aQuery = MyMongooseModel.find({});
aQuery.where("firstName").equals("Pat");
aQuery.exec(function(err, arMyMongooseModel){
    console.log("documents that have firstName='Pat'", arMyMongooseModel);
});
```

To add to the confusion, the Mongoose web page listed says to use `.$where()` which doesn't work.

**Is there a webpage/URL that contains a list of the operators available in a Mongoose Where clause?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query api docs at http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js seems to have what your looking for.

There is a [Query.$where()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-%24where) and [Query.where()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-where) with different usages. (See links)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I found that page as well, but it doesn't have a summary table like the Mongo page did, but this might be as good as it gets. If so, I'll mark this answer as accepted.  Thanks for pointing out that there are two functions ".$where()", and a ".where()".  I was looking at the wrong one!